# Type casting in Java from char to short

Tags: java, casting

Why can we not pass a `char` value as an argument to any method that accepts a `short` parameter, whereas we can pass a `char` value to another method whose parameter is of `int` type? Why does type casting not take place from `char` to `short`, given that the sizes are equal? I hope short can also store as much values as `short` can.

Comment: I've fixed up most of the question to read better as English, but I didn't understand the last sentence: "I hope short can also store enough values as much required for short" so I've left that as it was...

Answer (score 14):

> Why can we not pass a `char` value as a argument to any method that accepts a `short` parameter

Because there's no implicit conversion from `char` to `short` in an invocation context.

> whereas we can pass a `char` value to another method whose parameter is of `int` type?

That's because there *is* an implicit conversion available from `char` to `int` in an invocation context.

> Why does type casting not take place from `char` to `short`, given that the sizes are equal? I hope short can also store as much values as `short` can.

Although `char` and `short` are the same *size*, `char` is unsigned whereas `short` is signed. That's why there's no implicit conversion from `char` to `short`.

The conversion from `char` to`int` is a *widening* primitive conversion ([JLS 5.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)) whereas the conversion from `char` to `short` is a *narrowing* primitive conversion ([JLS 5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)). In particular (emphasis mine):

> A narrowing conversion of a char to an integral type T likewise simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. **In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the resulting value to be a negative number, even though chars represent 16-bit unsigned integer values.**

Answer (score 6):

Java specification says:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte,
> short, char, or int:
>
> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

Char has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 65,535.

Short has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767.

Integer has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647.

So char can fit into integer but not into short, that's why you should assure java that you want to do typecast here.

Comment: short as well as integer both can hold the sign and unsigned values but type casting is taking place in case of integer but not in short

Comment: Yes. Char has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 65,535. 
Short has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767.
Integer has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647. So char can fit into integer but not into short.

Comment: yes ...I got it .thanks a lot

Comment: I'll add this to answer